# Hibernate Batch Insert 150 records Oracle

Tags: java, hibernate, jdbc, oracle11g

I have a parent class as below

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "parent")
public class Parentimplements Serializable, Cloneable {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO, generator = "parent-seq")
@SequenceGenerator(name = "parent-seq", sequenceName = "parent_sequence")
private Long id;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "parent")
@Cascade({CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.ALL})
@Sort(type = SortType.NATURAL)
private SortedSet<Child> requirements = new TreeSet<Child>();
```

and trying to insert parent into oracle database with 150 children. With hibernate.jdbc.batch_size=50, its throwing Integrity violation parent key not found after 50 inserts. After increase batch size to 150, then after 150 inserts its throwing same exception including jdbc batch update exception.

Comment: please add the save method

Answer (score 0):

Two solutions come to mind:

1. Insert the parent record(s) first
2. Use DEFERRABLE constraints